# Storing checkbox values in database in JSP

Tags: java, sql, jsp

When I execute this code, it throws a `NullPointerException`. I want code for how to store the multiple checkboxes' values in JSP.

I select the 3 checkboxes' values in this code:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,javax.sql.*" %>

<%@ include file="DBCON.jsp"%>

<%
    String Branch=request.getParameter("Branch");
    String Yr=request.getParameter("Yr");
    String Sem=request.getParameter("Sem");
    String Sec=request.getParameter("Sec");
    String sub=request.getParameter("sub");
    String date=request.getParameter("date");
    String to_no_cls=request.getParameter("to_no_cls");
    StringBuffer sql=new StringBuffer();
    String[] ht_no=request.getParameterValues("ht_no");
    for(int j=0;j<=ht_no.length;j++)
    {
        System.out.println(ht_no[j]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=ht_no.length;i++)
    {   
        PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into attd_entry values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        pst.setString(1,Branch);
        pst.setString(2,Yr);
        pst.setString(3,Sem);
        pst.setString(4,Sec);
        pst.setString(5,sub);
        pst.setString(6,date);
        pst.setString(7,to_no_cls);
        pst.setString(8,ht_no[i]);
        pst.executeUpdate();
    }
    response.sendRedirect("attdentry.jsp");
%>
```

Comment: please state in your question solutions that you've tried and what was their outcome. SO is a place where people should give you hints not to the work for you.

Comment: You really shouldn't mix business logic and presentation. Look into how web frameworks split up JSP from the models you're persisting from the persistence mapping from input validation.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox will not be passed if it is not checked.  If it is checked it will be passed with value "on" by default. request.getParameter("checkbox1") will return null if it was not checked when the form was submitted.  Else if it is checked it will return "on".  Just check for the parameter(s) in question

```
String checkBox1;
variable = request.getParameter("checkBox1");
if(variable == null)
{
   //handle unchecked case
   checkBox1 = "0";
}
else
{
   //handle checked case
   checkBox1 = "1";
}
insert(checkbox, test, test, test);
```